# Inserting Text in new line without removing the previous text in Text View in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I am trying to Insert  Text in new line without removing  the previous text in Text View. I am very new in iOS so I am faciing little difficulty to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you put your textView's code ?

Comment: Are you asking how to append text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITextView insert text in the textview text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792589/uitextview-insert-text-in-the-textview-text)

Comment: Please search for existing answers before posting a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can do it quite easily by using the following code :

NSString *oldText,*newText,*myString; 




- (IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender {
[self updateTextField];
```

}

```
    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}



 -(void)updateTextField
{
    oldText=displayTextView.text;
    newText=entryTextField.text;
    myString = [newText stringByAppendingFormat:@"\n"];
    myString = [myString stringByAppendingString:oldText];
    displayTextView.text=myString;


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

When you add \n to the string, it will be converted to new line symbols

```
  aTextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@",aTextView.text,@"Second Line"];
```

Answer (score 0):

`textView.text = [(textView.text ?: @"") stringByAppendingString:(myText ?: @"")];`